# Why I get error when I try to display image?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I work use asp.net mvc5 in my project.

I try to display Image stored in my `Shared` folder in the project:

```
 <img src="@Url.Content(~/Views/Shared/logo.png)" alt="" />
```

But I get this  error on the fly:

```
Compiler Error Message: CS1525: Invalid expression term '/'
```

Any idea why I get the error above?

Comment: `src="@Url.Content("~/Views/Shared/logo.png")"`, you're missing the `"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@Url.Content` helper needs `string` as a parameter so you should write like this:

```
<img src="@Url.Content("~/Views/Shared/logo.png")" alt="" />
```

Comment: it's worked.Thank you. any Idea why I get broken Image?

Comment: @Michael there could be too many reasons. check your rendered html in browser to understand what's really happening

Comment: i never saw images located in Views >> Shared, Views directory is dedicated for Views

Comment: @EhsanSajjad agree, it's better place your image in Content folder

Answer (score 2):

or you can use single brackets

```
<img src='@Url.Content("~/Views/Shared/logo.png")' alt='' />
```